# blank page when printing the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, leaflet

I'm using javascript `window.print()` method to print a window and I'm removing unwanted components to print by adding display none inside `@media print` in my CSS. But my issue is it always shows a blank page after the 1st page which I need to print. I tried several solutions found online but nothing worked in my case.

my CSS used

```
@media print
{
    .noprint {display:none;}
    .leaflet-bottom {display:none;}
    .leaflet-control-container {display:none;}
    .leaflet-popup.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
        background: white;
    }
    html, body {
        height:100vh !important; 
        margin: 0 !important; 
        padding: 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        page-break-after: avoid !important;
        page-break-before: avoid !important;
      }
      #lmap:last-child {
       page-break-after: auto !important;
      }
    
      
}
```

Here is the view I need to print

```
  <div id="lmap"> ........ </div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a demo on jsfiddle or elsewhere

Comment: Try setting html, body height to unset

Comment: @netizen it didn't work either

Comment: Why do you need to set any `overflow` for your body? also `height` should not be set, it will automatically print everything there is.